Is it mandatory to have a function template to pass std::vector as an argument?
Is it mandatory to have a function template to pass std::vector as an argument as in the below code?
Also, in the parameter, why do we need to pass <T> along with std::vector?
template <typename T>
void print_vec(const std::vector<T>& vec){
    for(size_t i{}; i < vec.size();++i){
        std::cout << vec[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;    
}


int main(){

    //Constructing vectors
    std::vector<std::string> vec_str {"The","sky","is","blue","my","friend"};
    std::cout << "vec1[1]  : " << vec_str[1] << std::endl;
    print_vec(vec_str);
}


If you want to be agnostic to the value type of the vector passed in: yes.

Do you only call it with std::vector<std::string> or also with for example std::vector<int>? If only with the one, then void print_vec( const std::vector<std::string>& vec) is a sufficient function.

I assume you mean "is it mandatory to add std::string"... No it is not, but it will then be deduced to be a std::vector<const char*>

I honestly don't understand what you mean with "need to pass along with std::vector". Can you rephrase that? What would you expect or do instead?

ok understood, thanks everyone. template type function would be required only if we want to later use the same function for other data types.

No, it isn't mandatory. The author thought that a template print_vec was more useful than a print_vec that was specific to std::vector<std::string>.

Note in C++20 you can use this syntax,
and it basically restricts your template to anything "iteratable"
It also shows that in the case of ranges (vectors) you really should be
using range based for loops. (Regrettably most C++ courses are somehwat out of date and don't show you this)
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>

// Use C++20 template/concept syntax
auto print_all(std::ranges::input_range auto&& values)
{
    for(const auto& value : values)
    {
        std::cout << value << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> values{"1","2","3"};
    print_all(values);
}


I believe this needs to be non-const auto &&values, some standard views have non-const begin()/end(). Also ranges::input_range is probably a bit better than just range.

@HolyBlackCat Fair points ;) Updated

It's also worth mentioning std::span as an alternative. Templates can be overkill sometimes.
